# How does Ext JS set the minimum width of a textfield body?

Tags: width

Say that a textfield is flexed horizontally and no minWidth value has been set. If you resize the textfield to have a small enough width, the body will have its own default minimum width. The following is an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hp9

How does Ext JS set the minimum width of the textfield body?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I debugged, and I tried textfield.el.dom to show all the elements that composed the textfield. I found out that the element with a data-ref value of 'inputEl' had padding-left and padding-right values. I think that is what makes up the default amount of space of the body.